# Site can't be reached Virtual host Apache Manjaro

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

my httpd virtual host file

all sites access expect sachin.new are accessible.

"sachin.new" shows "site cannot be reached"

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sachin28new@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot "/srv/http/sachin/public_html/"
    <Directory  "/srv/http/sachin/public_html/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
  AllowOverride All

Require all granted
</Directory>
    ServerName sachin.test
    ServerAlias www.sachin.test
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/sachin.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/sachin.test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sachin28new@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/DCC/public_html/"
<Directory  "/srv/http/DCC/public_html/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
    ServerName dascc.test
    ServerAlias www.dascc.test
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/dascc.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/dascc.test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin sachin28new@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "/srv/http/sachinnew/"
<Directory  "/srv/http/sachinnew/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
    ServerName sachin.new
    ServerAlias www.sachin.new
    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/sachinnew.test-error_log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/sachinnew.test-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please show the actual detailed error messages. Chances are that it's not the Apache configuration.

Comment: error message and log files are empty

Comment: `site cannot be rached` is surely not the only message your client is showing. If yes, please use a command line client for the check and edit the complete output into your question.

Comment: run something like `curl http://sachin.new`

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov  output is <html>

<h1>This is a Test Sachin</h1>

</html>